# Python function for selective cummulative sum in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum, accumulate

I'm trying to loop through a DataFrame and accumulate a sum of values in one column based on the changes in values in another column.

Say I have a DataFrame looking something like this, and the 'accumulated_value' is the column I'd like to compute:

| input_value | criterion | accumulated_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 5 | 0 | 8 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 8 |
| 4 | 0 | 4 |

What I'm looking for is a way to tell Python "as long as the criterion value is the same, accumulate the input all input values and save the intermediary accumulated value in the new column'. Basically, I'd like to "draw" imaginary lines whenever the criterion variable changes value, and then apply np.cumsum() to all values between the two lines. I hope this question makes sense!

Is there any relatively straightforward way do do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Create a key to group on by using shift and cumsum. Then you can group on the key and cumsum the input_value

```
df['accumulated_value'] = df.assign(key=(df['criterion'] != df['criterion'].shift()).cumsum()).groupby('key')['input_value'].cumsum()

   input_value  criterion  accumulated_value
0            3          0                  3
1            5          0                  8
2            2          1                  2
3            6          1                  8
4            4          0                  4
```

Please reference the comment by @HenryEcker and note that you do not need to assign the result of the mask. Rather just groupby the series that the mask returns.

```
df.groupby((df['criterion'] != df['criterion'].shift()).cumsum())['input_value'].cumsum()
```

Comment: `groupby` can take a Series `df.groupby((df['criterion'] != df['criterion'].shift()).cumsum())['input_value'].cumsum()` no need to `assign` a temp key which can be _very_ expensive for larger frames. (+1 either way) =)

Comment: @HenryEcker you are absolutely correct. That is an oversight on my part. I will update my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks, this worked like a charm. 
Thanks @HenryEcker for the groupby() suggestion. I actually ended up reusing the assigned key for a different task this sime, but good to know that it's possible to avoid it for larger df.